# PingFederate Oracle Password Credentials Validator

Tags: oracle, passwords, credentials, pingfederate

My application has a user base both in LDAP and Oracle. I could set up an adapter and Password Credentials Validator (PCV) for LDAP successfully, however I am not able to find any documentation on how to configure PCV for Oracle. I don't see any TYPE for Oracle in the drop down of PCV screen.

Any help or documentation on how to configure a PCV and Adapter for Oracle?

Comment: Oracle has a significant number of products that could be used for a user repository... Are you inquiring about Oracle DB? Oracle Directory? Something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ping Identity only provides PCVs for LDAP products out of the box. Options for database validators exist:

1. you can build your own with the SDK (there is a sample PCV to use as
   a guide), as well as [this git](https://github.com/pingidentity/pf-pcv-sqlstoredprocedure). Please note that there is no
   support for these options (beyond what's provided by github).
2. contact your account team and purchase a custom integration.

Comment: I have created an sdk and followed the documentation to build and deploy. Now, when I try to create a new PCV, I don't see my sdk in the type drop down? Nor in the PCV list.

Comment: @Maz, did you look at the sample, and at the git I noted? If you've built a jar file, deployed it, and it's not working, then open a case for our support team. We can have a look at the code.  Or, post it here in a different question, tagged with PingFed again.

Comment: it worked after placing the source in plugin-src folder. Not sure why it has to present in there when I have a jar file. With this it works though.

Comment: Hi andrew, now that I have the working source code ready, I guess it will help others who is looking for similar setup. How do I upload it to ping github?

Comment: I'd start a conversation here: https://community.pingidentity.com/Group-Detail/Developer-Q&A

Comment: It says URL No Longer Exists

Comment: How about this one? https://community.pingidentity.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F940000000LGsd

Comment: Looks like stackoverflow eats up some part of the URL when you copy paste it here. Never mind, I guess you want me to post in Developer Q & A Community. Will post it there. Thank you.